# Get document metadata with powershell

Tags: powershell, metadata

I get my document with : `$doc = $web.GetFile($docUrl)`
Can you tell me if there is a method to get specific metadata on document?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean all columns related to document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Access metadata very easily. Here is an example code:

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$web = Get-SPWeb  "UrlOfWeb"
$doc = $web.GetFile("URLofFile") 
Write-Host $doc.Name
Write-Host $doc.Author
Write-Host $doc.ModifiedBy
Write-Host $doc.Versions.Count
```

Or did you mean sth else with "metadata", for instance custom properties (Property Bag)?